# Abrir libros con claves requeridas por inputbox de forma automática

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una serie de libros que cuando los abres te piden una clave si quieres poder acceder a las hojas que están ocultas con xlveryhidden. La cuestión es que quiero crear una macro que abra cada uno de estos libros y que se introduzca la clave en el inputbox emergente en cada uno de los casos. En lo que estoy atascado es, solamente, en que al abrirlos, la macro pueda introducir la contraseña en el inputbox.
¿Podriáis ayudarme con alguna idea?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No es que necesites "*que se introduzca la clave en el inputbox emergente*", sino que se debe abrir pasando la clave como parámetro en [**Workbooks.Open()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Especificando la clave de **acceso** al archivo (5° parámetro):

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\carpeta\archivo.xlsm",,,,"TuClave123")
```

O especificando la clave de **escritura** (6° parámetro):

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\carpeta\archivo.xlsm",,,,,"TuClave123")
```

(o ambas)

En tu caso, sería la clave de escritura (el 2do).

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta.
Aunque creo que te refieres a una clave que se pone al abrir el libro del mismo Excel. En mi caso no es así. Tengo una macro que cuando cierro el libro, oculta todas las hojas (xlveryhidden) excepto una y guarda el libro. Al abrirlo, te obliga a activar macros porque si no, no verías el resto del documento. Al activar las macros, un cuadro inputbox (otra macro) te pide una clave de acceso. Si es correcta, las hojas del libro se hacen visibles y si no, sólo ves una hoja que no tiene nada.

Comment: Lo que yo quiero es abrir este libro y poder meter la clave automáticamente en el cuadro inputbox que yo he programado.
Gracias de nuevo.